# How to allow reads ONLY from secondary for authenticated user in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, authorization

In a setup where users need to authenticate to MongoDB and then be granted access to db/collection, is it possible to only allow queries (find) on secondaries ?
If yes, how ?

This way, certains users wouldn't affect primary's performance.

Comment: do you mean you want all reads should go to secondary's but should not go to primaries at all ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
`Mongo.setReadPref()` 
and set read preference to
 `secondaryPreferred` on your replicaset.
however the drawback of it is Read operations using the secondary mode may return stale data.

Comment: I understand the compromise of having better performance at the cost of eventual consistency (stale data). You are showing how to actually use it from client side. My question is: as a dbadmin, how can I disallow users to read from primary ?

Comment: i am not really sure if you can enforce such a thing even if you are an admin. the only thing i can think off is to create uses with only read permissions and set read preference to secondary that way the users will automatically be routed to the secondaries...